# Byte Order Mark (BOM) being generated by PHP-FPM

Tags: php, byte-order-mark, fpm

I have a PHP script which serves up a jpeg image in response to an http query.

```
ob_start();
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');     // don't want any caching
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-Length: $len");
readfile($fn);
ob_end_flush();
```

This script works fine with Apache mod-php7 (Ubuntu 16.04), but the same script with Apache and PHP-FPM (Ubuntu 20.04) results in the jpeg stream being prefixed with a BOM - which the browser sees as an invalid jpeg.

I also tried saving the query response with wget, and I can see the BOM as the first 3 bytes of the response body, after the headers.

If I fetch the jpeg directly, bypassing my script, everything is ok.

I'm satisfied that the BOM is NOT present in the buffer at ob_end_flush() - (I temporarily added a filter to ob_start to examine the buffer)

So it looks like php-fpm is adding the BOM for some reason. There's nothing in the php-fpm error log.

What could be causing this?

Comment: The BOM could be in your `.php` script file itself, before the `<?php` tag

Comment: Thx. I checked that with hexdump. There's no BOM.